# Laravel Query depend on Multiple HTML Select tags

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I've multiple `Select` tags in HTML form i.e 'Gender', 'District' etc where the default selection is `All`. The eloquent query is dependent on these tags. I can retrieve data from DB if user select an option like `Male` or `Female` but don't know how to use `All'.

here is html code of `Gender` Select tag.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <select wire:model="byGender" class="custom-select form-control" name="gender" id="gender">
        <option selected>All</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="combine">Combine</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and here is Laravel Code

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->rows = DutySheet::where('gender', $this->byGender)->get()->toArray();
}
```

Note: this is Livewire function and `byGender` will be updated as the user select an option.

My question is what to use as value of `All` option in `Select` tag to retrieve all data from DB, `""` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `All` options are represented by empty values (empty strings). You can leverage this by using the `when()` method on the query-builder, which effectively is an if-statement - the closure is only applied to the querybuilder if the first parameter is true.

```php
$this->rows = DutySheet::when($this->byGender !== '', function($query) {
                    return $query->where('gender', $this->byGender)
                })
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

You can chain these and add as many `when()` as you want to your query, to compute a more complex query with conditional conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logic to only apply the `where` condition when the select menu is set to any value other than "All".

If the user selects male, female or combine then the where condition will be run against that value, otherwise the query will return every record.

```
public function mount()
{
    $dutySheets = DutySheet::query();
    
    if ($this->byGender !== 'All') {
        $dutySheets->where('gender', $this->byGender);
    }

    $this->rows = $dutySheets->get()->toArray();
}
```

Comment: as I mentioned there are multiple 'Select' tags. What if one is 'All' and other is 'Other then All' or both are 'ALL' or both or 'Other then All'. Please update your answer.

Comment: Can a user select multiple options at the same time?

Comment: yes. user can select one or many option at the same time